# Boxplot showes incorrect picture

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have my code which shows stats:

```py
data = data.assign(
    ArrDelay=np.where(data["ArrDelay"].lt(0), 0, data["ArrDelay"]),
    DepDelay=np.where(data["DepDelay"].lt(0), 0, data["DepDelay"])
)
data[["ArrDelay", "DepDelay"]].head(40)
data['Month'] = (data['ArrDelay'] + data['DepDelay'])

result = data.groupby("UniqueCarrier")["Month"].mean()
print(result)
sns.boxplot(x='UniqueCarrier', y='Month', data=data, order=result.index)
```

But the boxplot is incorrect.

There is my result:
[image]

How I'd like it to be:
[image]

Comment: I have fixed description

Comment: The boxplot looks like this because you have a huge number of values close to zero, and a smaller, but still large, number of outliers.  Maybe a log-scaled y-axis would help a bit? And/or using `sns.boxenplot` to show more detail.  You could further try to set the zero values in the `Month` column to `np.nan`, so they don't get counted.

Comment: So, did you exclude the latency values above the 95th percentil?  You could `plt.ylim(ymax=100)` to hide the large outliers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should remove the outliers with the `showfliers` option:

```py
#... 
sns.boxplot(x='UniqueCarrier', y='Month', data=data, order=result.index, showfliers = False)
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. I really appreciate your effort!